# How to display/hide overlapped divs in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, dom-events

I am working on Javascript to parse an XML file and then display it properly in HTML.

I am very new to all these technologies. What I am doing is parse the XML and generate the html form and user can perform submit action on it. I am successfully displaying the form. But I am generating the form inside **for loop** under **new div** each time and then assigning the newly div to **TD** of a table. Now I want to display particular div when user clicks on the **label**, but since it is generated in loop they overlapped to each other, so it is displaying only the last div.

How can I display/hide overlapped divs in Javascript?

Here is my [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gga3jpm6/).

And the **XML** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CONTROLLERS>
    <CONTROLLER>
        <TITLE>User</TITLE>
        <ACTION>
            <LABEL>Create User</LABEL>
            <HTTP_METHOD>POST</HTTP_METHOD>
            <PARAMS>
               <PARAM><NAME>email</NAME></PARAM>
               <PARAM><NAME>user_name</NAME></PARAM>
               <PARAM><NAME>first_name</NAME></PARAM>
               <PARAM><NAME>last_name</NAME></PARAM>
            </PARAMS>
        </ACTION>
        <ACTION>
            <LABEL>Update User</LABEL>
            <HTTP_METHOD>POST</HTTP_METHOD>
            <PARAMS>
               <PARAM><NAME>id</NAME></PARAM>
               <PARAM><NAME>email</NAME></PARAM>
               <PARAM><NAME>user_name</NAME></PARAM>
               <PARAM><NAME>first_name</NAME></PARAM>
               <PARAM><NAME>last_name</NAME></PARAM>
            </PARAMS>
        </ACTION>
    </CONTROLLER>
    <CONTROLLER>
        <TITLE>Admin</TITLE>
        <ACTION>
            <LABEL>Create Admin</LABEL>
            <HTTP_METHOD>GET</HTTP_METHOD>
            <PARAMS>
               <PARAM><NAME>email</NAME></PARAM>
               <PARAM><NAME>admin_name</NAME></PARAM>
               <PARAM><NAME>password</NAME></PARAM>
            </PARAMS>
        </ACTION>
    </CONTROLLER>
</CONTROLLERS>
```

Currently the view looks like

[image: View]

Comment: Your fiddle isn't working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Better use css classes and call them in jQuery methods. Z-Index would make help you solve the problem of overlapping `<div>`s.

Comment: can you provide any example, I dont know about jQuery